# How to refactor this pattern of code in python?

Tags: python

```
class Nova_AZ0(models.Model):
    sampleTime = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.FloatField(default=0)

class Nova_AZ1(models.Model):
    sampleTime = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.FloatField(default=0)

class Nova_AZ3(models.Model):
    sampleTime = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I want to create three different class. They just have different name AZ. How to refactor these code to make it neat?

Comment: If you're only doing this a few times, this is likely the neatest way. You could always define a class factory if you need to create many classes with a few small differences (like default arguments, etc), which could just be a function returning a class.

Comment: Make a common subclass (maybe `Nova_AZ`?), which inherits from `models.Model`, then have each of the 3 classes inherit from your `Nova_AZ` class. This may not be very practical if you are going to create a lot of child classes.

Comment: To be honest, I'd be more concerned about your database schema having a bunch of similarly named tables with the exact same fields.

Comment: not exactly, not the same fields. I just need four different tables with different names.

Comment: what do you mean by class factory? How to implement that? Can you elaborate on this? I search a few sample in google, but don't get a glue.